# Creating users with has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm trying to use has_secure_password on my user model, but have found that while it works in the application it breaks all my tests. I have a simple user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password
    attr_accessible :email

    validates :email, :presence => true,
              :format => { :with => /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i },
              :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
    validates :password, :presence => true
end
```

My first test (rspec) simply confirms that I can create a new user with valid attributes:

```
describe User do
    before(:each) do
        @attr = { :forename => "Captain",
                  :surname => "Hook",
                  :email => "email@test.com",
                  :password => "password",
                  :password_confirmation => "password" }
    end

    it "should create a new instance given valid attributes" do
        User.create!(@attr)
    end
end
```

This doesn't work, however when I do

```
user = User.new(@attr);
user.password = "password";
user.save
```

it works fine. I believe this is because has_secure_password adds a new method, password, which deals with the generation of the `password_digest`, so calling it directly like this generates the fields that I need. Is there any way I can use User.create but still call this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was really simple. Since I hadn't added :password to `attr_accessible` it wasn't populating the field when I called `User.create` or `User.new`. The only modification I needed to make to the code was

```
attr_accessible :email, :password
```

Comment: `attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation`

Comment: How do you it in Rails 4? I'm asking because in Rails 4 there is no 'attr_accessible' anymore.

Comment: You have to use `attr_accessor` instead.